# What is $\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{10}x (\sin 12x )\,dx\;$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos^{10}x )(\sin 12x )dx$$

I am unable to figure out the trick this question expects me to use. Its not a simple by parts question.

If I denotes the integral then I is also equal to $\int_0 ^{\pi/2}(\sin^{10}x) (\cos 12 x)dx$

Adding the two I's , doesn't yield anything special.

How do I go about solving this problem? What's the trick to immediately recognize the method the integration questions expect me to use?

Comment: *Mathematica* gives the answer instantly:  $1/11$.

Comment: It's possible to write $\sin(12x)$ as $Q_{12}(\cos x) \sin x$ for some polynomial $Q_{12}$, so then you could do a substitution $u = \cos x$.

Comment: One quick suggestion:  When writing titles, please include some text, instead of solely mathjax.  With text, a user can right click on the text to open your question in a new tab, which I invariably do for every question that I visit.  When a title is all and only mathjax, there is no way to do this; if I try right clicking on only a mathjax title, my only options are to view the source/formatting.  No way to open the question in a new tab.

Comment: @amwhy I agree with you, but you can also do Ctrl+ click to open in new tab.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hint: the integrand can be written as
$$\begin{align}
  & ={{\cos }^{10}}\left( x \right)\sin \left( 11x+x \right) \\ 
 & ={{\cos }^{10}}\left( x \right)\left( \sin \left( 11x \right)\cos \left( x \right)+\cos \left( 11x \right)\sin \left( x \right) \right) \\ 
 & ={{\cos }^{11}}\left( x \right)\sin \left( 11x \right)+{{\cos }^{10}}\left( x \right)\cos \left( 11x \right)\sin \left( x \right) \\ 
 & =-\frac{1}{11}\frac{d}{dx}\left[ {{\cos }^{11}}\left( x \right)\cos \left( 11x \right) \right] \\ 
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest rewriting this with exponentials using [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula); then you just need to multiply it out and trivially integrate the exponentials. It's perhaps not the most elegant way to do it, but it's straightforward. The [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) does most of the work of multiplying it out for you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint :
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dx}(\cos^{11}x \cos(11x)) =-11\cos^{10} x \sin x \cos(11 x) - 11 \cos^{11} x \sin(11x).
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use the $\sin$ addition formula.

Answer (score 2):

$$I = \int \cos^{10}x(\sin 12 x)dx$$

$$I = \Im\int \bigg[e^{i(12 x)}\cdot \bigg(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\bigg)^{10}\bigg]dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{2^{10}}\Im\int \bigg[e^{i(2x)}\cdot \bigg(e^{i(2x)}+1\bigg)^{10}\bigg]dx$$

Now put $e^{i(2x)}+1=t,$ Then $\displaystyle 2ie^{i(2x)}dx = dt\Rightarrow e^{i(2x)}dx = \frac{dt}{2i}$

So $$=\Im\bigg[\frac{1}{2^{10}i}\int t^{10}dt\bigg] = \frac{1}{2^{11}\cdot 11}\Im\bigg[\bigg(\frac{e^{2ix}+1}{e^{ix}}\bigg)^{11}\cdot e^{11ix}\bigg]+\mathcal{C}$$

$$=-\frac{1}{11}\Im\bigg[\cos^{11}(x)\cdot \bigg(\cos 11 x+i\sin 11 x\bigg)\bigg]+\mathcal{C}$$

So $$I = -\frac{1}{11}\cos^{11}(x)\cdot \cos (11x)+\mathcal{C}$$

So $$\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\cos^{10}x(\sin 12 x)dx = -\frac{1}{11}\bigg[\cos^{11}(x)\cdot \cos(11)\bigg]\Bigg|^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}=\frac{1}{11}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\begin{align}
\sin x\sin y &= \dfrac12(\cos(y - x) - \cos(y + x)) \\
\cos x\cos y &= \dfrac12(\cos(y + x) - \cos(y - x)) \\
\sin x\cos y &= \dfrac12(\sin(y + x) - \sin(y - x))
\end{align}$$

Also,
$$\begin{align}
\cos^{10}x\sin 12x &= (\cos^2x)^5\sin 12x \\
&= \left(\dfrac12(\cos 2x + 1)\right)^5\sin 12x \\
&= \dfrac1{32}\left(\cos^52x + 5\cos^42x + 10\cos^32x + 10\cos^2x + 5\cos 2x + 1\right)\sin 12x
\end{align}$$
and so on. Using the product-to-sum formulas above and linearity, you should be able to solve the integral.

Answer (score 1):

The solution holds in a word: *linearise* the expression, starting from *Euler's formulæ*. Here's how to start:
\begin{align}
\cos^{10}x\,\sin 12 x&=\Bigl(\frac{\mathrm e^{ix}+\mathrm e^{-ix}}{2}\Bigr)^{\!10}\,\frac{\mathrm e^{12ix}+\mathrm e^{-12ix}}{2i}\\
&=\frac{\mathrm e^{10ix}+10\mathrm e^{8ix}+45\mathrm e^{6ix}+\dotsm}{2^{10}}\cdot\frac{\mathrm e^{12ix}+\mathrm e^{-12ix}}{2i}
\end{align}
Can you proceed?